# Android error: package com.actionbarsherlock.view does not exist

Tags: android, macos, actionbarsherlock

[image: Cannot find ActionSherlockBar in downloaded unzipped archive]

How can I resolve this problem? I am sure ABS is added as shown in this image. In fact, I just ran it from the downloaded unzipped folder! I am using Mac, Android Studio. Why is this error coming up?

Comment: `makeText(PictureDemo.this, .... , ....);` at least for the error that I can see

Comment: I am sure this code runs as is from the original Commonsware (commonsguy). I will perhaps fix any other errors after I resolve the ABS issue.